# Can Django infer a view name from the url?

Tags: django

I have the following urls

```
url(r'^signup/','social.views.signup'),
url(r'^submit_signup/','social.views.submit_signup'),
url(r'^signup_complete/','social.views.signup_complete'),
```

Could I make a url that would choose the view based on the url? Like:

```
url(r'*/', 'social.views.*')
```

so that a request to /signup would route to 'social.views.signup'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somehow like this

```
def test(*args,**kwargs):
    view_name = kwargs.pop('view')
    view = getattr(social.views,view_name)
    return view(*args, **kwargs)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^test/(?P<view>.*)$', test),
    ...
)
```

or like this

```
VIEWS_LIST = ['signup','submit_signup','signup_complete']
urlpatterns = patterns('social.views',
    *[url('%s/' % view,view) for view in VIEWS_LIST]
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I wish there was a more implicit way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make signup process of multiple steps than you can user Django form wizard. In this way you don't need to change url for every signup step. The URL will look like this:

```
url(r'^signup/$', SignupWizard([SignupForm_1, SignupForm_2, SignupFormComplete]) ),
```

Check the [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) documentation.